# AWS CodeArtifact error with 401 Unauthorized when trying to upload with twine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, twine, aws-codeartifact

I'm having issues pushing python package into CodeArtifact using twine. I would love your ideas on what this might be and how to debug this.

I've setup the repository following [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/python-configure-twine.html).

Running `aws codeartifact login --tool twine` is successful and I see the password updated in the `~/.pypirc` file:

```
$ aws codeartifact login --tool twine --repository myrepo --domain mydomain --domain-owner 111122223333 --region us-east-1 --profile myprofile

Successfully configured twine to use AWS CodeArtifact repository https://mydomain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/myrepo/
Login expires in 12 hours at 2022-11-03 06:52:46-04:00
```

but then when I try to upload I get an unauthorized error:

```
$ twine upload  --verbose --repository myrepo ./dist/mylib-0.0.2.tar.gz
INFO     Using configuration from ~/.pypirc
Uploading distributions to https://mydomain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/myrepo/
INFO     ./dist/mylib-0.0.2.tar.gz (7.8 KB)
INFO     username set by command options
INFO     password set by command options
INFO     username: aws
INFO     password: <hidden>
Uploading mylib-0.0.2.tar.gz
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.3/13.3 kB • 00:00 • 26.8 MB/s
INFO     Response from https://mydomain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/myrepo/:
         401 Unauthorized
INFO     Unauthenticated: request used expired credentials. Please renew your credentials.
ERROR    HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized from https://mydomain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/myrepo/
         Unauthorized
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I created a new repository and migrated to it. After a while deleted the problematic repository. Never got to the bottom of this.